# How does solving this system yield to such results?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

$$\begin{cases} (1-\lambda_i)x+y = 0 \\x-\lambda_iy = 0 \end{cases} \iff \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\in\left\langle\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_i\\1\end{pmatrix} \right\rangle$$
I have tried to solve it in various manners and none yields to that result for x and y.

Comment: Any information on what $\lambda_i$ is? Since there's an index $i$, I suppose that it is not just something random or arbitrary. At the very least, $\lambda_i$ must satisfy $\lambda_i-\lambda_i^2+1=0$. If not, the statement is simply wrong.

Comment: Are you trying to find eigenvalues/eigenvectors of a certain matrix?

Comment: This system comes from computing A-xI and the lambdas correspond to the eigenvalues of A. However I cannot connect this fact to the obtained identity.

Comment: You had to include that information in your post. Anyway, use Cramer's rule to solve the system to prove the forward direction. The backward direction is pretty straightforward and you should just plug in $x=\alpha \lambda_i$ and $y=\alpha$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ in the system.

Comment: I had done an error, pointed by @J. W. Tanner : the second root is $1-\Phi$, not $\Phi-2$ as I wrote it. I have fixed it in my text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform your system into the form eigenvalue-eigenvector :

$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}}_M\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\lambda_i\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$$

Matrix $M$ has characteristic equation

$$\lambda^2-\lambda-1=0,\tag{1}$$

Thus, its eigenvalues are

$$\lambda_1=\underbrace{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}_{\text{Golden ratio} \ \Phi}\ \ \text{and} \ \ \lambda_2=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}=1-\Phi$$

These eigenvalues being distinct, the dimensions of their eigenspaces is 1. Thus you can drop out the brackets ($\langle$ and $\rangle$) : you have simplified your issue into the plain checking that :

$$\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_i\\1\end{pmatrix} \ \text{is an eigenvector associated with} \ \lambda_i$$

for $i=1,2$.

Let us check it for $i=1$, i.e., for $\lambda_i=\Phi$ :

We must have (coming back to your initial system) :

$$\begin{cases} (1-\Phi)\Phi+1 = 0 \\ \Phi-\Phi \times 1 = 0 \end{cases}$$

The second equation is clearly verified. The first one is equivalent to $\Phi^2-\Phi-1=0$ which is true because $\Phi$ is a root of equation (1).

Comment: Did you mean $\lambda_2=\Phi-\sqrt5$?

Comment: @J. W. Tanner You are right. Thank you very much. I fix it. I will give the slightly simpler form $1-\Phi$.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are trying to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix, specifically $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$
The second equation is enough to show that the vector is proportional to your right side for any given eigenvalue $\lambda_i$.  Plugging that into the first equation gives
$$1+\lambda_i-\lambda_i^2=0$$
which you can solve to find $$\lambda_i=\frac {1\pm \sqrt 5}2$$